# Inherited class needs parameter for base class constructor

Tags: c++, oop, c++-cli

I made 2 managed classes in C++ clr, and I have a constructor on the base class. The derived class is inheriting from the base one, and I believe that since my constructor on the parent class has parameters not equal to void, that when I call it to be inherited it needs a parameter for the constructor. I believe this because when I stop inheriting, the error goes away. I can't just put (parameter) after inheriting it, so my question is how do I get it to be inherited without asking for a parameter for the constructor.

Here is my full error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2512   'ConnectDB': no appropriate default constructor available   Credit Card Storage System  C:\Users\dehla\Desktop\Visual Studio Projects\C++\Credit Card Validator\Query.h 26
```

Here is my Header File:

```cpp
#ifndef DATA_BASE
#define DATA_BASE

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

ref class ConnectDB{
protected:
    SqlConnection^ cnn;
    String^ sql_file;
    bool state;

public:
    ConnectDB(System::String^ in_file);
    bool ConnectDataBase();
    ~ConnectDB(void);
};

ref class Query : public ConnectDB{
private:
public:
    
};

#endif
```

Here is my cpp file:

```cpp
#include "Query.h"

ConnectDB::ConnectDB(System::String^ in_file){
    sql_file = System::IO::File::ReadAllText(in_file);
}

bool ConnectDB::ConnectDataBase() {
    String^ connectionString = "Data Source=WIN-50GP30FGO75;Initial Catalog=Demodb;User ID=sa;Password=demol23";
    SqlConnection^ cnn = gcnew SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cnn->Open();

    state = true;
    return true;
}

ConnectDB::~ConnectDB() {
    cnn->Close();
}
```

Comment: Side note: I know this is CLI, but you may want to cover your ass by observing the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Say you accidentally copy a `ConnectDB` instance. You will have two objects, both referring to the same `SqlConnection`. And when that copy goes out of scope, it's gonna `cnn->Close();` and cripple the other copy. In this case I'd disable the copy constructor and assignment operators so you can't have an accident.

Comment: @ComyarD what's going to happen when you don't have an in_file given (e.g. the `""` case in @JosephLarson answer)?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for reminding me to remove the declaration there and just replace it with a definition made for the declaration made in the .h file. I forgot to change that when I moved the declaration to the h file.

Comment: @MrR I'm planning on replacing the "" with the path the the sql file I made, so "script.sql"

Comment: Just need to declare them as private (i.e. `private: ConnectDB(ConnectDB const&);` and same for assignment op).  Don't need any implementation - it's just extra syntax to prevent copying [will get an error like in the question if unintentionally try to].

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "querry" - one "r" is *QUITE* enough !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subclass doesn't need a constructor with arguments, but all constructors need to call the base class constructor properly.

As the base class doesn't have a default constructor, you need to do something like this:

```
class Query : public ConnectDB{
private:
public:
    Query(): ConnectDB("") { ... }
    
};
```

The thing is, unless you want to hardcode the value input to `ConnectDB`, your base class probably needs a constructor with a string parameter so you can forward it to `ConnectDB's` constructor.

Comment: Thanks man. I knew I had to declare it somehow, I just didn't know how.

Comment: Someday teachers will start giving the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) the respect it deserves. Until then...

Comment: @user4581301 C++ is hard, and there's a lot going on for students to understand. While it would be great if we could properly layer small amounts at a time, some of this is just freakishly intertwined.

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* a header file is only part of the code - in this case it's showing the declarations (i.e. the specification of the classes).  Presumably you have a file with the actual implementations of the methods.

The code is missing a declaration for the constructor on the `Query` class.  The implementation will need to call the 1 arg constructor, but the declaration doesn't need to indicate that.

Comment: My bad that I didn't add the cpp source code, I just added it.